# Is it Okay to add another person (except the supervisor, advisor, and the student) to the paper extracted from master's thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis, plagiarism, author-order

I am writing a paper extracted from my master's thesis. A friend of mine helps me a lot during this process. Is it Okay to add his name to my paper?

Answer (score 4):

Why would you not?
Authorship guidelines (see e.g. [here](https://provost.yale.edu/policies/academic-integrity/guidance-authorship-scholarly-or-scientific-publications), [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines) or [here](https://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html)) commonly state three criteria:

1. Everyone listed as an author has made a substantial intellectual contribution to the paper. The opposite is also true: everyone who has made a substantial intellectual contribution to the paper should be an author.
2. All authors should contribute to the writing of the paper or, at least, critically review the paper's contents.
3. All authors claim responsibility for their respective part of the paper, integrity and veracity of the reported results.

A caveat here is that any author should take a part in reviewing the paper draft or write parts of it, and you should not report results obtained by other people without their validation. On the flip side, you do NOT have to include your supervisor nor advisor if they did not contribute substantially to the paper's contents. In some academic communities, it may backfire, but including those and only those who "made the paper happen" is the most ethical thing to do. Keep in mind that substantiality of a contribution is in the eye of a beholder, so the best practice would be to decide on authorship, including both the list of the people involved and the author order, BEFORE you have started working on a project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If my supervisor does not agree with adding another person, what should I do?

Comment: @MahsaTmri Unfortunately, it may happen indeed - after all, ethics is something to strive for, and it does not come as a granted. But that is the exact reason you discuss these matters *beforehand*. Imagine you are building a house planning to sell it to a person, you have done everything and now they are refusing to pay. What now? If you had prior written agreements, you could try to enforce them (but even then, life is not always fair). Sit down with your supervisor and discuss authorship before you set out to work. You know you have no leverage after the fact, so why drag it?

Comment: Note that a thesis advisor/supervisor often has intellectual input by guiding your work and setting directions. However if the advisor then refuses authorship you could just acknowledge them instead.